# GParted change is not permanent Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I try to resize a harddrive from a Ubuntu 22.04 booted from a pendrive. The harddrive is not mounted and contains some data I don't want to loose. Before, there was a separate drive that run Ubuntu 20.04 got broken and now, I would like to have the system (temporarely) on the data disk.

When I made some room with GParted and it finished succesfully, in a second, the newly created partition disappear and the partition has the same size as before the shrinking. It has `ext4` format. The drive is `/dev/sda`. GParted only sees this and the pendrive since I removed the broken disk.

I got no error message during the process. I applied the pending operation, i.e., used that green mark on the top menu. There is no other OS on the disk. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Sounds like you failed to comment the changes.

Comment: There's definitely a bug in gparted that fails to commit changes after committing changes. All you need to do is reboot and then you will see some or all of the changes not committed at all.  Use a professional tool. Gparted can't handle more than 4 partitions reliably.

Answer (score 1):

Commit changes;
= click the green tick, without it the changes you have listed will not be done.

Here an inactive tick, which cannot be clicked on
*(as I do not wish to mess with my partitions ;-)*

[image]

Comment: Hi Hannu, Thanks for your comment and yes, I forgot to mention that I did what you suggest. So I right click on the drive ```/dev/sda``` , then set the new size and then Apply pending operation. It finishes in around a minute and then, for a second, it seems like everything is all right but then the bar that indicates the partitions on the drive jumps back to its original state. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Boot the install media you created to install Ubuntu in "Try ubuntu"-mode, then try this from there instead. This to eliminate (avoid) any possible quirky software being present and having this effect. Hmm... **might be** you need to run `sudo apt install gparted` from Bash/Shell/Terminal to make gparted available.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing. GParted is already there. But I made a step further that might be helpful for others but not for me at the moment.
After I resized the drive the newly freed space appear. Before I hit the Apply button, I have to right click on the it and click New and select some options. I think that would make it permanent but unfortunatelly, the process run in some errors. The details are not clear because the saved log doesn't open. Otherwise the error message is that "Something went wrong, please read the details." But my original question might be answered.

Comment: See comment above - gparted is very unreliable and doesn't always commit changes it says it does.